# Entity Framework code-first migration fails with update-database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am new EF code first. I study from https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application When I write update-database, I get this error:

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
>   to the target database. Applying explicit migrations:
>   [201806161013068_ColumnFirstName]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201806161013068_ColumnFirstName. Caution: Changing any part of an
>   object name could break scripts and stored procedures. Running Seed
>   method. System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires
>   a target.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj, Object[] index)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression
>   me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression
>   expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
>   at ContosoUniversity.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(SchoolContext
>   context) in
>   C:\Users\Bengisu\source\repos\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line
>   119    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext
>   context)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Non-static method requires a target.

in line 119, there is

```
var eInDb = context.Enrollments.Where(s => s.Student.ID == e.Student.ID
                  && s.Course.CourseID == e.CourseID).SingleOrDefault();
```

My Configuration.cs:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContosoUniversity.Data_Access_Layer.SchoolContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis",    LastName = "Barzdukas",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan",      LastName = "Li",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy",    LastName = "Justice",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura",    LastName = "Norman",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino",     LastName = "Olivetto",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-08-11") }
            };
            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course {CourseID = 1050, Title = "Chemistry",      Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 4022, Title = "Microeconomics", Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 4041, Title = "Macroeconomics", Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 1045, Title = "Calculus",       Credits = 4, },
                new Course {CourseID = 3141, Title = "Trigonometry",   Credits = 4, },
                new Course {CourseID = 2021, Title = "Composition",    Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 2042, Title = "Literature",     Credits = 4, }
            };
            courses.ForEach(s => context.Courses.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
            {
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.A
                },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.C
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Macroeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                     StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Calculus" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                     StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Trigonometry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Barzdukas").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Li").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Justice").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Literature").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 }
            };

            foreach(Enrollment e in enrollments)
            {
                var eInDb = context.Enrollments.Where(s => s.Student.ID == e.Student.ID
                  && s.Course.CourseID == e.CourseID).SingleOrDefault();

                //if the enrollment is not found in the database
                if (eInDb == null)
                {
                    context.Enrollments.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**With -verbose option:**

> PM> Update-Database –Verbose Using StartUp project
>   'ContosoUniversity'. Using NuGet project 'ContosoUniversity'. Specify
>   the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the
>   target database. Target database is: 'ContosoUniversity2' (DataSource:
>   (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin:
>   Configuration). No pending explicit migrations. Running Seed method.
>   System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a
>   target.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj, Object[] index)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression
>   me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression
>   expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
>   at ContosoUniversity.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(SchoolContext
>   context) in
>   C:\Users\Bengisu\source\repos\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line
>   119    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext
>   context)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Non-static method requires a target.

Comment: Do update with -verbose option and add the result to your question

Comment: I added result of update with verbose @CodeNotFound

Comment: Why don't you use `AddOrUpdate` for `enrollments`?

Answer (score 1):

Was getting this particular error. Turned out to be the code in Seed Data around user creation.

Pay close attention to `ApplicationUser.UserName` - I put dashes and it failed to create users.